# Why does a certain program need .NET Framework and SQL Server?

Tags: anti-virus, .net-framework, sql-server

My question is not intended to provoke a deep discussion, I'm just looking for peace-of-mind.

I'd like to download and play this simple game:

http://download.cnet.com/UnBlockMe/3000-2111_4-75629311.html?tag=mncol;6

In the requirements, the following is listed:

**.NET Framework 4 Client Profile**

**Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition**

Since I'd be downloading from a trusted site, I shouldn't worry about malware so much. However, as someone who has no idea what installing an "sql server" on his machine can lead to, I hesitate. Could installing that open a back door at some point (and completely unrelated to the game itself)? Will I have to tend to updates and the like? etc.

Out of curiosity, why would such a seemingly simple game need such extra programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework is needed as the application is built using that as a run-time platform, in later Windows releases it is actually a part of the operating system. The SQL Server Compact Edition is also a Component that is used to store information locally on your computer, like game results and progress. It is not the same as big full blown product called "SQL Server" and the parts needed is probably included in the game installer.